# Converting plain text file to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string

So, I've hit a mental break down with the following code, I'm trying to parse a plain text file with the following contents:

```
name = rattlesnake
alias = snake,rattle
health = 50
flee = 45
attacks
    bite = [3, 8, 30]
    punch = [5, 12, 90]

name = bear
alias = bear
health = 100
flee = 15
attacks
    claw = [10, 15, 60]
```

I have the following code that I have written so far, but I hate it and it doesn't do what it's supposed to. I've been trying for hours now. Here's the function:

```
var parseModFile = function(contents) {
    var hasTab = /(?<=\t).*$/;
    var split = contents.split("\r\n");
    var pushIt = "{";
    var numExtraBraces = 0;
    var closeBrace = 0;
    for (var l = 0; l < split.length; l++) {
        var doIt = "";
        if (split[l]) {
            if (split[l].length > 1) {
                if (hasTab.test(split)) {
                    doIt = split[l].replace(/\t/g, "");
                    if (doIt.indexOf(" = ") > -1) {
                        doIt = doIt.split(" = ");
                        var key = doIt[0];
                        var val = doIt[1];
                        if (key.length > 0 && val.length > 0) {
                            if (closeBrace == 2) {
                                doIt = "},\"" + key + "\": \"" + val + "\",";
                                closeBrace = 0;
                            } else {
                                doIt = "\"" + key + "\": \"" + val + "\",";
                            }
                            if (closeBrace == 1) {
                                closeBrace++;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        doIt = doIt.split(" = ");
                        var key = doIt[0];
                        doIt = "\"" + key + "\": {";
                        numExtraBraces++;
                        closeBrace = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            pushIt += doIt;
        }
    }
    for (var b = 0; b < numExtraBraces; b++) {
        pushIt += "}";
    }
    pushIt += "}";
    return pushIt
}
```

Which is ALMOST correct, but is returning this:

```
{
    "n": "rattlesnake",
    "a": "snake,rattle",
    "h": "50",
    "flee": "45",
    "attacks": {
        "bite": "[3, 8, 30]",
    },
    "n": "bear",
    "a": "bear",
    "h": "100",
    "flee": "15",
    "attacks": {
        "claw": "[10, 15, 60]",
    }
}
}
```

Which obviously isn't quite right, I'd like it to be:

```
{
    "n": "rattlesnake",
    "a": "snake,rattle",
    "h": "50",
    "flee": "45",
    "attacks": {
        "bite": "[3, 8, 30]",
    }
},
{
    "n": "bear",
    "a": "bear",
    "h": "100",
    "flee": "15",
    "attacks": {
        "claw": "[10, 15, 60]",
    }
}
```

But I cannot get it to fit at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A - I don't understand the question? I'm not counting attributes. The code iterates line by line, finds tabs, finds `=` then parses.

Comment: no dude its a while; I'm writing the regex from scratch; yours is not readable

Comment: My regex is `/(?<=\t).*$/`... What are you writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution, but for the purpose you need, it gives a valid JSON output.

You need to tweak it somewhat, because I used a plain text input with line-breaks.

Hope it helps:)

PS: it needs the [] brackets, because otherwise it is not valid JSON.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    let chunk = data.split("\r\n");
    let end = [];
    for(let chun of chunk) {
        if(chun === "") {end.push("}},{"); continue;}
        let it = chun.replace(/\t/g, "").replace("    ", "").replace(/\n/g, "").split(" = ");
        switch (it.length) {
            case 1:
                end.push(`"${it[0]}":{`);
                break;
            case 2:
                end.push(`"${it[0]}":"${it[1]}",`);
                break;
        }
    }
    console.log("[{"+end.join("")+"}}]");
});
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"rattlesnake","alias":"snake,rattle","health":"50","flee":"45","attacks":{"bite":"[3, 8, 30]","dookie":"[1, 2, 5]",}},{"name":"bear","alias":"bear","health":"100","flee":"15","attacks":{"claw":"[10, 15, 60]","rawr":"[1, 4, 7]",}}]
```

Comment: Hmm, The output isn't correct with multiple attacks. Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/mcgb4HRL

Comment: Actually it is. Sorry I mixed things up a little to show the results one line at a time.

Comment: Corrected it, it should just be JSON.parse-d and it should be usable

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see. Actually I didn't know you need multiple attacks. I will see if I can solve the issue

Comment: How about now? Unfortunately if you change the template it will again be broken. Not sure how much it will change in the future

Comment: Thanks mate, but the iterations seem to be broken now :D https://pastebin.com/XpcUGKNm Sorry to be a pain...

Comment: It seems there was a little problem between the way I tried to replicate line-breaks and how it actually is in a file. Now it returns a valid output for me

Comment: Abso-bloody-lutely perfect. Thank you VERY much!!

Comment: No worries, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Here is more compact, easier to read, super customizable regex;

```
const content = ` your string `;

let result = ("{\n" + content +"\n  }\n}")
.replace(/=\s(\w.+)/g,': "$1"')
.replace(/=/g,':')
.replace(/\]/g,'],')
.replace(/,\n\n/g,'\n  }\n},\n{\n')
.replace(/(\w+)\n\s{4}/g,'$1 : { \n    ')
.replace(/\"\n/g,'",\n')
.replace(/(\w+)\s:/g,'"$1" :')
.replace(/\],\n\s+\}/g,']\n  }');

//making it a valid json by making it an array 
result = "[\n" + result + "\n]" ;
```

Here is a code snippet showing the output;

```js
const content = `name = rattlesnake
alias = snake,rattle
health = 50
flee = 45
attacks
    bite = [3, 8, 30]
    punch = [5, 12, 90]

name = bear
alias = bear
health = 100
flee = 15
attacks
    claw = [10, 15, 60]`;

let result = ("{\n" + content +"\n  }\n}")
.replace(/=\s(\w.+)/g,': "$1"')
.replace(/=/g,':')
.replace(/\]/g,'],')
.replace(/,\n\n/g,'\n  }\n},\n{\n')
.replace(/(\w+)\n\s{4}/g,'$1 : { \n    ')
.replace(/\"\n/g,'",\n')
.replace(/(\w+)\s:/g,'"$1" :')
.replace(/\],\n\s+\}/g,']\n  }');

//making it a valid json by making it an array 
result = "[\n" + result + "\n]" ;

console.log(JSON.parse(result))
```